# Is there a way to do a wildcard with a GROUP BY in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Suppose I have two tables: tbl_a contains an id field "id" and a whole bunch of other fields "fa", "fb", ... "fz". (with all ids unique)

tbl_b contains two fields "id" and "value" - where there could be multiple values for the same id. I want to make a table with the same fields as in tbl_a, but with an additional field giving the average "value". This can be done as:

```
SELECT
tbl_a.id AS id
ANY_VALUE(tbl_a.fa) AS fa
...
ANY_VALUE(tbl_a.fz) AS fz
AVG(tbl_b.value) AS avg_value
FROM
tbl_a JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.id AS tbl_b.id
GROUP BY tbl_a.id
```

My question is:

> Is there a way to write this query without having to explicitly write in every field that you want to transfer from the old to new table?

If there were no GROUP BY then this could be done using a wildcard, but I don't see how to do it where there is a GROUP BY, since the wildcard would effectively have to be within the ANY_VALUE().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ANY_VALUE(a).*, AVG(value) avg_value
FROM `project.dataset.table_a` a
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table_b` b
USING(id)
GROUP BY a.id
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table_a` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 11 fa, 12 fb, 13 fc UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 21, 22, 23 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 31, 32, 33
), `project.dataset.table_b` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 value UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 7 
)
SELECT ANY_VALUE(a).*, AVG(value) avg_value
FROM `project.dataset.table_a` a
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table_b` b
USING(id)
GROUP BY a.id
-- ORDER BY a.id
```

with result

```
Row id  fa  fb  fc  avg_value    
1   1   11  12  13  2.0  
2   2   21  22  23  5.0  
3   3   31  32  33  7.0
```